# How to remove the waveform box for midi Sound?

Tags: gui-construction, sound

For midi sounds, the bottom box in the DisplayForm is always blank, I'd like to be able to remove it:

```
Sound[{SoundNote["C"], SoundNote["G"]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just a quick hack:

```
customSound[s_] := Module[{playCode, boxForm, skin,notes},
    boxForm = ToBoxes @ s;
    playCode[] := Cases[boxForm, _EventHandlerTag, {0, \[Infinity]}, Heads -> True][[1, 1, 1, 2]];
    skin = boxForm[[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];
    Panel@Labeled[ToExpression[skin],
        Grid[{{Button["play",playCode[]]},
        {Button["stop",Sound`StopMIDI[]]}}]
    , Left]
]
customSound[Sound@{SoundNote["C"], SoundNote["G"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nasty hack. The functional pieces are the elements inside the BoxForm, it would be great to have a direct way of generate that without resorting to parsing the boxes!

Comment: You may be interested in taking a look at the `InputForm` of the composite output; click on the graphics output by `Sound`, copy it and paste it to a new input cell, then wrap it in `InputForm`. Notice that you have to go through the copy/paste step, otherwise `InputForm` will simply return your `Sound` expression. See here for a sample of the results: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Sih.png). I'm afraid that it's probably not that much better than the box expressions, but perhaps it's more readable!

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for the feedback :)